# Build problem in Xcode - library not found for -liconv

Tags: xcode

I have a problem when building in xcode - library not found for -liconv

Please help me solve this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Rlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should type the following commands in the terminal.app.

```sh
#brew search iconv
#brew install libiconv
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs few times due to iOS version mismatch with main project exists. Just navigate to your :Build Settings > Deployment > iOS Deployment target and check if it is the same as main project, if not, make it the same.